# How is OutputIterator related to std::back_inserter and std::ostream_iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

While looking at `std::copy_if` details at [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_if/), the 3rd argument is an `OutputIterator`.

```
template <class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class UnaryPredicate>
  OutputIterator copy_if (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                          OutputIterator result, UnaryPredicate pred);
```

I have below code which is using  `std::back_inserter` as the 3rd argument. When i look at `std::back_inserter` details [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) , then it doesn't mention it as an `OutputIterator`.

1. Is `OutputIterator` any class OR just a way to indicate any Iterator which can output something?
2. Is `OutputIterator` related to [ostream_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) somehow?
3. Why its mentioned [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) that  Incrementing the `std::ostream_iterator` is a no-op. What does it mean? Does it mean that we can't do a ++ on `std::ostream_iterator`?

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec {1, 22, 3, 4, 5, 12, 14};
    std::vector<int> rvec;
    
    std::copy_if(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), std::back_inserter(rvec), [](const int& x){ return (x % 2 == 0);})
      

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OutputIterator` here is an exposition-only name for the template parameter. It has no specific functionality.

The linked site unfortunately doesn't specify which types are allowed as template argument for `OutputIterator`. If you take instead e.g. the [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) page for `std::copy_if`, you see that it specifies that the type must be a *LegacyOutputIterator* (aka an *output iterator*).

This is a term describing specific requirements that the type must satisfy in order to be allowed to be used with `std::copy_if`.

An output iterator type is just an iterator type which allows writing to the dereferenced iterator.
For the details see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/OutputIterator.

---

On the page you linked for `std::back_inserter`, it says that it is a function returning a `std::back_insert_iterator`. When you use `std::back_inserter(...)` in the argument list of `std::copy_if`, you are passing it this returned object, not the `std::back_inserter` itself.

If you click on the name of that type on the linked page, you will see that it specifies that `std::back_insert_iterator` is a *LegacyOutputIterator*.

So, it is allowed to be used in `std::copy_if`.

---

`std::ostream_iterator` is also an output iterator and therefore usable in `std::copy_if`. It is only used to "iterate" and write to `std::ostream` streams. It is not related to `std::back_inserter`. It is not related to `std::vector` either and you are not using it in your example.

"Iterate" here is not quite correct, because it doesn't really iterate anything. When writing to the dereferenced `std::ostream_iterator` it simply outputs the value to the associated `std::ostream`. This is why it says that `++` on it is a noop. There is nothing to do to advance it.